# Haskell consecutive sublist of list

Tags: list, haskell

Hi I have this little function which finds the powerset of set but i need all the consecutive sublist. `[1,2,3] -> [[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3]]` and not `[[],[3],[2],[2,3],[1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`

Is there a way to fix this function to do what i want?

```
sublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
sublists [] = [[]]
sublists (x:xs) = sublists xs ++ map (x:) (sublists xs)
```

Comment: Is element order significant in the answer?

Answer (score 6):

It's not exactly elegant, but you can use `divvy` from `Data.List.Split`:

```
xs = [1,2,3]
[] : concat [ divvy n 1 xs | n <- [1..length xs] ]
-- [[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Michael Kohl is not buildable.
Divvy is already returning [[a]] so the list comprehension is returning [[[a]]]. I would just add a comment, but not enough reputation to do that.
Use concat.

```
sublists xs = [] : concat [ divvy n 1 xs | n <- [1..length xs]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you just want the result that you already have, but with a different arrangement of the elements. In that case, one easy and not at all elegant way would be sorting after performing `sublists`. The function that decides the order of the elements would be:

```
subCompare x y = case (compare (length x) (length y)) of 
     EQ -> compare x y 
     s -> s
```

This means, compare by length, but if they have the same length, then compare by elements order.
And then:

```
> sortBy subCompare (sublists [1,2,3])
[[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is almost a simple recursion, in that if we want `sublists [1,2,3,4]` and we already have the sublists of the tail, that is...

```
[[], [2], [3], [4], [2,3], [3,4], [2,3,4]]
```

...it's fairly obvious that to handle the new element `1`, the new sublists we need to add are `[1]`, `[1,2]`, `[1,2,3]`, and `[1,2,3,4]`.  The problem is it isn't obvious where these new
sublists should be inserted.

To make it easier we can do a slightly different recursion which keeps the sublists of
each length separate in their own lists, so we'll have

```
[[[]],
 [[2], [3], [4]],
 [[2,3], [3,4]],
 [[2,3,4]]]
```

Now it's more obvious where to insert the new
sublists.

The final result will just be the concatenation.

```
sublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
sublists = concat . sublists'

sublists' :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
sublists' [] = [[[]]]
sublists' (x:xs) = zipWith (++) withX withoutX
  where
    ysss = sublists' xs
    withX = [] : [[x:ys] | ys:_ <- ysss]
    withoutX = ysss ++ [[]]
```

Notes:

- We need to make withX and withoutX the same length so that the
  zipWith doesn't run out early, and since `withoutX` already contains
  the zero-length sublist we need to *not* include that in withX.
- I could have written `withX` using `inits (x:xs)`, but that would
  make new lists instead of sharing some of those we have in `ysss`.
  (Although whether maximal sharing is good sometimes depends on how you
  consume the result.)
- `sublists'` can also be written as a `foldr`.

Answer (score 1):

Though not in the order you asked for,

```
import Control.Monad((<=<))
import Data.List(inits, tails)

-- inits [x, y, z, ...] = [[], [x], [x, y], [x, y, z], ...]
-- tails [x, y, z, ...] = [[x, y, z, ...], [y, z, ...], [z, ...], [...], ..., []]
-- (f <=< g) x = do  y <- g x
--                   f y
-- (f . g) x   = let y = g x
--                in f y

sublists = ([]:) . (tail . inits) <=< tails
```

This uses the fact that the list monad models nondeterminism: `tails` nondeterministically selects where the sublist begins, `inits` selects where it ends, there’s some munging to get nicer(?) behavior for empty lists, and the list monad takes care of iterating all possible combinations of start and end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand the question but if so, you can use `combine` of the `combinat` package:

```
> import Math-Combinat-Sets
> map (`combine` [1,2,3]) [0..3]
[[[]],[[1],[2],[3]],[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[2,3],[3,3]],[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[2,2,2],[2,2,3],[2,3,3],[3,3,3]]]
```